# Powershell Delete aged MSMQ messages in specific queue

Tags: powershell, queue, msmq, message

Alright, so new to dealing with MSMQ messages in power shell.  And I am sure I am making a stupid rookie mistake.  I want to delete any message older than X days from a specific queue.  If anyone has some thoughts on how to do it right, I'll take it.    Here is what I have:

```
$today = Get-Date
$today = $today.Adddays(-30)
$queuePath = (".\$private\thequeueIwant")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
$queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queuePath
$queue.GetAllMessages
{
if ($_.ArrivedTime -lt $today)
    {
     $message.delete
     }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're opting to not manage the lifetime of your messages using the `TimeToBeReceived ` functionality? This would drop any expired messages into the dead-letter queue.

Comment: Ah, well.  I'll look into that.  With out going into all the different details, where I am at, that change will be out of my scope.  I am assuming it needs to be set by the thing creating the messages.
But, while I am looking at that, if there is any input on how to create the script to do this all the same, that would also be welcome

Comment: That's a correct assumption, yeah. The sender is responsible for managing message lifetime.